# Markdown to PDF conversion in Python, issue with symbols

Tags: python, pdf, markdown, file-conversion

I am trying to convert a Markdown file to a pdf, by firstly converting it to HTML and then to a PDF file.

This is my code:

```
from tomark import Tomark

data = {
    "EC2 - Other":"1.224009E-4",

    "AmazonCloudWatch":"3.3099916",

    "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute":"34.582367",

    "Amazon Virtual Private Cloud":"43.2"
}

for key, value in data.items():
    data.update({key:"€" + value})

transposed_list = []
for k,v in data.items():
    transposed_list.append({"Service": k, "Cost": v})

print(transposed_list)
markdown = Tomark.table(transposed_list)
print(markdown)

with open(r'path_to_file', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(markdown)
    pass


#doc = aw.Document("new_md2.md")
#doc.save("Output2.pdf")

from markdown import markdown, markdownFromFile
import pdfkit

input_filename = r'path_to_md_file'
output_filename = 'README.pdf'

with open(input_filename, 'r') as f:
    html_text = markdown(f.read(), output_format='xhtml', extensions=['markdown.extensions.tables'])

with open('html_format.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_text)
print(html_text)

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=r"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
pdfkit.from_string(html_text, output_filename, verbose=True)
```

The output of the PDF does not recognize the € symbol. Does anyone know how to fix this?
The output looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJomE.png)

Comment: Does the font you are using contain that character?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by font?

Comment: When you make documents you use characters (aka "A", "B", etc ...). Formatting solutions put those characters inside the PDF by character *and* what font it should be in. If you are not specifying any kind of font in your setup, it is possible/likely that you are putting characters in the PDF in some default font like Helvetica or Times. These fonts do not have every character and in fact most (if not all of them) do not have the EURO glyph. Hence, you see nothing

Comment: It would be the filename encoding that mattered. Please share the encoding name (how this would be selected/reviewed would depend on your editor).